# How to Search for a Value in All Messages on Telegram using the gram.js API?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a project where I need to search for a specific value across all messages in a Telegram chat using the gram.js API. However, I'm not sure how to implement this feature. Can someone guide me on how to search for a value in all messages using the gram.js API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.